# sun.security.util.DerValue not found on WAS

Tags: java, tomcat, websphere, sftp, jsch

I have an java application which runs fine on tomcat 5.5. But when deployed on WAS 7 it throws an exception. It try to connect to a sftp server to retrieve some files but it throws the exception.

---

### Error trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun.security.util.DerValue
at com.sun.crypto.provider.DHPublicKey.<init>(DashoA12275)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.DHKeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair(DashoA12275)
at java.security.KeyPairGenerator$KeyPairGeneratorImpl.generateKeyPair(KeyPairGenerator.java:234)
at com.jcraft.jsch.jce.DH.getE(DH.java:57)
at com.jcraft.jsch.DHG1.init(DHG1.java:110)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.receive_kexinit(Session.java:601)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:320)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
```

The java.security file has the following providers:

```
security.provider.1=com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE
security.provider.2=com.ibm.crypto.provider.IBMJCE
```

I'm lost. Any Idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the package states, DerValue is a Sun class.

```
sun.security.util.DerValue
```

WebSphere uses IBM JDK, which not include this class. Only IBM JCE providers are supported.

> security.provider.1=com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE

Taking this line away probably will resolve your problem and the application will run as expected.

If you intend to use SunJCE, take a look at [this IBM tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0306_yu/yu.html).

Using IBM default implementation is an easier option and I would go for that. I would not recommend adding Sun JCE as a custom provider because you'll need to keep this step as a pre-requisite for deploying your application and reproduce it every time you need to change something in a new server.

Comment: You're right, deleting the line is the solution. Thanks!